# docker-composer up -d getting error postgres: Bind for 0.0.0.0:5432 failed: port is already allocated

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am on the Mac with docker install `version 2.0.0.3 (31259)`

docker-compose up -d

```
Removing ab-insight_postgres_1
Starting ab-insight_data_1 ... done
Recreating 31d36fb9c48a_ab-insight_postgres_1 ... error

ERROR: for 31d36fb9c48a_ab-insight_postgres_1  Cannot start service postgres: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ab-insight_postgres_1 (5ed1c634dd3a43c2cd988ff7f14b5c1f3cde848e375c2915cf92420f819e21ac): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:5432 failed: port is already allocated'

ERROR: for postgres  Cannot start service postgres: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ab-insight_postgres_1 (5ed1c634dd3a43c2cd988ff7f14b5c1f3cde848e375c2915cf92420f819e21ac): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:5432 failed: port is already allocated'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - /home/flask/app/web
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 project:app
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /www/static
    volumes_from:
      - web
    depends_on:
      - web

  data:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql
    command: "true"

  postgres:
    restart: always
    build: ./postgresql
    volumes_from:
      - data
    expose:
      - "5432"
```

and here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.6.1
MAINTAINER Ka So <kanel.soeng@kso.com>

# Create the group and user to be used in this container
RUN groupadd flaskgroup && useradd -m -g flaskgroup -s /bin/bash flask

# Create the working directory (and set it as the working directory)
RUN mkdir -p /home/flask/app/web
WORKDIR /home/flask/app/web

# Install the package dependencies (this step is separated
# from copying all the source code to avoid having to
# re-install all python packages defined in requirements.txt
# whenever any source code change is made)
COPY requirements.txt /home/flask/app/web
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the source code into the container
COPY . /home/flask/app/web

RUN chown -R flask:flaskgroup /home/flask

USER flask
```

run `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to postges running locally on your machine on the same port you have mentioned in your docker-compose.yml for postges service.
Either stop the sevice running on your local machine.(not recommended)
Or use other port to map to 5432 port of docker. To do so replace the

```
expose
  -5432
```

in postgresa service with the following code

```
 ports:
      - "5433:5432"
```

The whole docker compose file will look like:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - /home/flask/app/web
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 project:app
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /www/static
    volumes_from:
      - web
    depends_on:
      - web

  data:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql
    command: "true"

  postgres:
    restart: always
    build: ./postgresql
    volumes_from:
      - data
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
```

Comment: I got this `ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.postgres.expose is invalid: should be of the format 'PORT[/PROTOCOL]' `when I replace expose 
`

Comment: Did you type expose instead of ports